# How to manipulate raw string SQL statement with C#

Tags: c#, sql, string

I am transferring a database. I have sixty thousand lines of SQL insert statements. Since some fields in the old database are not in the new database, I need to edit the statements I have.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Product (Name,Count,Brand,Type,Code) VALUES ("Toys",4,NULL,"Child Toy","T001")
```

the expression for the new database should be:

```
INSERT INTO Product (Name,Count,Type,) VALUES ("Toys",4,"Child Toy")
```

this process is also valid for different table structures so i am looking for a permanent solution.

i write this solution:

```
string s="INSERT INTO Product (Name,Count,Brand,Type,Code) VALUES ("Toys",4,NULL,"Child Toy","T001")"

s.Replace("Code", "");

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

but this solution is very primitive. how can i solve this?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: I am not an expert but why to call something primitive if you do not know a better way... Asking for help is just enough... Just a note...

Comment: Are those statements generated or did you wrote them manually? Can't you deal with generator?

Comment: This insert statements in .sql file. i mus manipulate columnt to new table. and i failed :/

Comment: your issue is, because it the way you started, but seeing as it is what it is, what i would do... is read the lines as is, without `INSERT INTO Product (Name,Count,Brand,Type,Code) VALUES (` so values only, then cast them to typed version in code, then you can either use a framework to do the inserts or, then write to text file with the amendment you want. or just do this with notepad still both and manual.

Comment: Don't have the time to prototype something, sorry, but, you could create a dictionary, key being columns, values being the values, then, remove what you need from the dictionary, and build the query back up from there. You could load the table definitions as well, so you know what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small console app which does the trick...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INSERT INTO Product (Name,Count,Brand,Type,Code) VALUES (\"Toys\",4,NULL,\"Child Toy\",\"T001\")");
            Console.WriteLine(GetCorrectedInsertStatement("INSERT INTO Product (Name,Count,Brand,Type,Code) VALUES (\"Toys\",4,NULL,\"Child Toy\",\"T001\")", "Brand", "Code"));

        }

        private static string GetCorrectedInsertStatement(string sqlInput, params string[] columnssToRemove)
        {
            string sqlOutput = string.Empty;

            if (columnssToRemove.Length == 0)
            {
                return sqlInput;
            }

            int indexOpenBracket = sqlInput.IndexOf('(');

            // Copy prepare sqlOutput with INSERT INTO [Table] ({0}) VALUES ({1})
            sqlOutput = sqlInput.Substring(0, indexOpenBracket) + "({0}) VALUES ({1})";

            // Remove INSERT INTO [COLUMN] from sqlInput
            sqlInput = sqlInput.Substring(indexOpenBracket, sqlInput.Length - indexOpenBracket);

            int indexCloseBracket = sqlInput.IndexOf(')');

            // Get Coumn1,Column2,... 
            string tmpColumns = sqlInput.Substring(1, indexCloseBracket - 1);

            // Split to get all columns
            List<string> columns = tmpColumns.Split(',').ToList();

            // Remove Coumn1,Column2,... from sqlInput
            sqlInput = sqlInput.Substring(indexCloseBracket, sqlInput.Length - indexCloseBracket);

            indexOpenBracket = sqlInput.IndexOf('(');

            // Remove VALUES from sqlInput
            sqlInput = sqlInput.Substring(indexOpenBracket, sqlInput.Length - indexOpenBracket);

//UPDATED the next line from IndexOf to LastIndex of.
            indexCloseBracket = sqlInput.LastIndexOf(')');

            // Get values to insert from sqlInput
            string tmpValues = sqlInput.Substring(1, indexCloseBracket - 1);

            // Split to get all values
            List<string> values = tmpValues.Split(',').ToList();

            // remove the columns and values that are no longer needed
            foreach (string columnToRemove in columnssToRemove)
            {
                int indexToRemove = columns.IndexOf(columnToRemove);
                columns.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
                values.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
            }

            // insert the columns and values into the sqlOutput
            sqlOutput = string.Format(sqlOutput, string.Join(", ", columns.ToArray()), string.Join(", ", values.ToArray()));
            return sqlOutput;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution is awesome. but i stuck at 'second' ( character. 

for example: VALUES(CAST(xxx) as DATETIME) scenario throw error. how can i denied this?

Comment: @SametÖz: I've made a small change to the posted code to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use your existing statements with just a single change to the table name.

First, create a view and a trigger:

```
create view vwProduct as 
select  [Name], [Count], null as [Brand], [Type], null as [Code] from Product
```

```
create trigger ProductTrigger on vwProduct
instead of insert
as
begin
    insert into Product
    select [Name], [Count], [Type] from inserted
end;
```

Now you will be able to run your existing statements by just changing `Product` to `vwProduct`:

```
INSERT INTO vwProduct (Name,Count,Brand,Type,Code) VALUES ("Toys",4,NULL,"Child Toy","T001")
```